# Websolr solr version

Tags: heroku, solr, sunspot-rails, websolr

We are looking to use the 'soft commit' feature in Solr4 to support near real time search for our production application on Heroku.

1. Does Websolr on Heroku support Solr4?
2. If yes, is it possible to use the sunspot rails gem to play nicely with a Websolr Solr4 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and yes.  Solr4 will become the default in Websolr sometime in March/April 2014, but for now you have to log into the Websolr control panel to create your Solr4 instance... the addon won't do it itself.  If you need help navigating, please fill out a ticket on http://help.websolr.com, and someone can help you.

Comment: that's great news. Thanks Kyle.

Comment: I looked at the add new instance section -- there is a Solr4.4 server group in EC2 but in the Solr configuration section there is only a Sunspot 2.0 for rails 3 option. There is no Sunspot 3.0 for Solr 4 option in it. Will selecting Sunspot 2.0 option work for integration with Solr 4?